# Does conditional convergence of a series implies convergence of its square?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to figure out if for a series $\sum{a_k}$ that converges conditionally , the series $\sum{a_k^2}$ must converge.

I am thinking this statement is false but I am struggling to find a counterexample.

For example I have in mind the series $\sum{\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}}$ but this series converges absolutely, so I am trying to find a series $a_k$ that only converges conditionally in order to show that its square diverge.

I know a series converges conditionally when a series converges but does not converge absolutely.

I cannot think of any such series so far so any help is appreciated.

Update: I believe the counterexample I have in mind is actually correct as the comments below mentioned since $\sum{\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}}$ does not converge absolutely as it is a p-series with $p=\frac{1}{2} < 1$.

Comment: $\sum \frac {(-1)^{k}} {\sqrt k}$ does not converge absolutely.

Comment: The example you gave only converges conditionally. So that would make a counterexample of the first statement you gave.

Comment: yes you re right! i can see that now.